# Pip uses a different python version than the one I installed

Tags: python, macos, pip, pygame, homebrew

I installed Python 3.8.2 on Mac OS with Homebrew. I added the directory to PATH, but it seems to have installed wrong versions. I tried to install pygame with pip3, but when I ran the .py with python3, it told me the module was missing. `pip3 --version` tells me it uses Python 3.7. However, `pip3.8 --version` tells me it uses Python 3.8. Both `python3 --version` and `python3.8 --version` show "Python 3.8.2". I'm really confused - is there something really obvious that I'm missing? Did Python not find pygame because pip installed it on another version of Python?

Comment: "Did Python not find pygame because pip installed it on another version of Python?" Yes it looks like you installed pygame to Python 3.7 and then tried to import it from Python 3.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, always use virtual environments and do not install packages globally.

Second, I was back then dealing with this confusion, too. After lots of research, I gave up and finally decided to go with the following command, even though I would want to just type `pip` or `pip3`.

`python3.8 -m pip install pygame`

This way, you install the package(pygame here) for a specific version of python(3.8 here).

You can find something more detailed in [here](https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/).

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall pip using your current python:

```
python3 -m pip install -U pip
```